# discord.py how to use client.login instead of client.run

Tags: discord.py

I have searching the web for 2 hours on how to this i eventually just gave up.
so basically im trying to make a discord bot (i know how to make one) but im trying to use client.login / client.connect instead of client.run i just want an example of a discord bot that can sign into any account with the token and do something. And i know your gonna ask "Where is the code?" well i don't have the code im just looking for an example not a fix.
but if you must see

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import discord
import asyncio
token = open("token.txt", "r").read()  # I've opted to just save my token to a text file.
#User = discord.User()
client = discord.Client()
#@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("on ready executed")
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for memberd in guild.members:
            str = memberd.id
            user = client.get_user(str)
            await user.send('test')
            print(memberd)
    client.login(token)
#client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know if you want to use client.login you do

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

client.login()
```

Note that client is old and it is better to use cogs and use commands.Bot()
eg.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, Context

client = Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event()
async def on_ready()
    print("[Status] Ready")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx:Context):
    ctx.send("pong")

client.run("Token")
```

But if you still want to use the old discord you could use it